# Zend_framework-Issue with loading mysql.so extension (_zend_list_find )

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm trying to install mysql.so extension for php 7.0. Unfortunately, I have this problem:

```
PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/mysql.so' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/mysql.so: undefined symbol: _zend_list_find in Unknown on line 0.
```

I've searched internet for the solution and I didn't find anything. I tried also installing zend-framework, but nothing happened.

Comment: Try to use mysqli

Comment: `zend framework` has nothing to do with `_zend_list_find`